# rest-assured body(InputStream) does not work

Tags: java, unit-testing, rest-assured

I am using `rest-assured` **4.3.3** (the version is forced by the newest Spring Boot 2.5.0).

Rest-assured interprets the `InputStream` as `Object` and cannot handle it. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> in IntelliJ IDEA (Javadoc) over `.body(getInputStream())`, it shows the signature [`RequestSpecification body(InputStream body)`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/4.4.0/io/restassured/specification/RequestSpecification.html#body-java.io.InputStream-) so the compiler should understand properly which of the the heavily overloaded `.body()` methods is supposed to be used.

However, when I replace `getInputStream()` with `getFile()`, it works. That's how I know that the `XML` in the resource file is correct.

The [documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/static/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/4.4.0/io/restassured/specification/RequestSpecification.html) says for both the methods `body(File body)` as well as `body(InputStream body)` exactly the same:

> Specify file content that'll be sent with the request.

So my understanding is that these are just two alternative ways how to pass the body if I have it in a file.

My code:

```java
class MyTest  {
    @Value("classpath:/valid-request.xml")
    private Resource validRequest;
    ....
    @Test
    void myTest() {
        given()
                .header("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8")
                .header("SOAPAction", "myService")
                .body(validRequest.getInputStream())  // this does not work
//              .body(validRequest.getFile())  // this works
        .when()
                .post("/myApi")
        .then()
                .log().ifValidationFails()
                .statusCode(200)
                .contentType("text/xml")
        ;
        
    }
}
```

Error message:

```txt
java.io.BufferedInputStream@6ceb953
2021-06-11 17:35:47.083 ERROR [,628aa0b986fe0c98,628aa0b986fe0c98] 11428 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap          : SAAJ0511: Unable to create envelope from given source
```

I think that it is caused by a bug in rest-assured, but just for a check, maybe you might spot a flaw in my code better than I.

Anyway, I created an issue https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/1480.
The same error has been reported as "fixed" in the closed issue https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/1040.

Answer (score -1):

Actually no, it's not a bug.
It says `InputStream` as a method parameter, because it expects that you will pass an object, which will be interpreted and serialized by InputStream.
The best way is to use POJO-classes for request body payloads, however in your case I'd suggest to go ahead and read that file as a `String` and pass as a param into `body()`, this should be working.

Comment: The documentation https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/latest/io/restassured/specification/RequestSpecification.html says for ***both*** `body(File body)` ***and*** `body(InputStream body)` exactly the same: "Specify ***file content*** that'll be sent with the request." So how have you come to your interpretation?

Comment: By the way, I disagree with the statement "the best way is to use POJO-classes for request body payloads", because it you pass the body as `XML`/`JSON` this is more similar to what you have in production, and the test is then **more relevant**.

Comment: Why should I read the file as `String`, if I can pass it as `Resource.getFile()`? Why bother with doing something which the library does for me for free? I was just wandering that as I understand the documentation, rest-assured should work **both** with `body(File)` **and** `body(InputStream)`.