# How to upload file in RestAssured for PUT (non-multipart) request

Tags: rest, file-upload, put, rest-assured

I'm working on automating the PUT API which expects file to be sent as `InputStream`. We used `curl` request to test this locally and now need to automate using RestAssured. I went through the documentation of RestAssured [RequestSpecBuilder.setBody()](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.0.5/io/restassured/builder/RequestSpecBuilder.html#setBody-byte:A-) which works only for `POST` methods and doesn't work for `PUT`.

Any pointers on how to upload file to PUT API using RestAssured would be helpful.

Below are details :

- Curl command used `curl -v --location --request PUT 'http://localhost:1080/update' "${HEADERS}" --upload-file <<FILE_PATH>>`
- API Definition :

```
@PUT
public Response updateResource(@Context final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                              @NotNull final InputStream inputRequestBody) {
     // Do processing
}
```

Comment: According to the documentation you can use `InputStream` as the request in Rest Assured. 
 Check `body(InputStream body)` method in [RequestSpecification Documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/static/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/4.4.0/io/restassured/specification/RequestSpecification.html).  But seem to be there is an issue with `InputStream` in Rest Assured. [Github Issue](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/1040).  And `body(File body)` also works instead of `body(InputStream body)`.  Check https://stackoverflow.com/q/67939950/5257981

Answer (score 0):

given().multiPart() is used to upload a file.
The syntax will be similar to:

```
given().multipart("createJS", new File(D:\\Automation\\filepath"), "application/json")
```

You will need to change path and file type.

Comment: We don't have multipart request. We have a PUT API which takes in file as `InputStream`. So above solution wouldn't work.